# How to prevent file sharing with Quick Look PDF viewer

Tags: objective-c, quicklook

I am using the QuickLook framework to display PDFs in my app. The pdfs are downloaded and stored in my apps sandbox, in the Application_Support directory.
Basically, I open the PDF in my app, no problems and then close my app.
Now if I open the Adobe App on my device, the pdf I was viewing with my app is available in
the Adobe app.

Is there any way of preventing this sharing of my pdf between my app and the Adobe App

Any help will be much appreciated

j

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to hide the right navigation button on the Quick Look Viewer nav bar.